# Cascaded and nested if statements in C programming language

Tags: c, if-statement

What is the difference between cascaded if statements and nested if statements in C programming language?

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: `cascaded if statements` I was reading about something like this in `C#` but not for `C`

Comment: Does cascaded check for 1(true) or 0(false) some number of variants ?

Comment: first or second or third itc, and nested check if first if statement true between statements puted inside of this if statement

Comment: i am reading King  C book btw

Answer (score 3):

Cascaded:

```
if (condition1)
{
    // do one thing
}
if (condition2)
{
    // do other thing
}
```

Here, if `condition1` is true, `one thing` will be done. Again, if `condition2` is true, `other thing` will be done too.

Nested:

```
if (condition1)
{
    // do one thing
    if (condition2)
    {
        // do other thing
    }
}
```

Here, if `condition1` is true, `one thing` will be done. And, if `condition2` is *also* true, `other thing` will be done too.

Note that in the latter case, both the conditions need to be true in order for `other thing` to happen. While in the first case, `other thing` happens if `condition2` is true, irrespective of `condition1` being true or false.

Comment: I don't think is true, cascade is ==>> `if{}else if{}else if{}.......{}else{}` [See here](http://palmsforcs1.pbworks.com/w/page/13844712/CascadingIf)

Comment: ^What you are referring to is called an if-else-if ladder.

Comment: Yes, also know as Cascading If Statements

Comment: @Michi: It might be, but grammatically this is also a nested one. Just a different formatting to avoid runaway indentation.

Comment: As far as my knowledge of English serves, cascading `if` is a series of `if` statements only.